# How to add new rule in firebug related to existing .css file

Tags: css, firefox, firebug

I have a `.html` file with a `.css` file linked on.

In firebug, I can add a new rule but it create it related to the .html file.

Can I create it for my `.css` file ?

For exemple, I created `.ngscope` rule but I want it to be related to `app.css`, not `index.html`

Possible ?

[image: http://img856.imageshack.us/img856/5296/ekbi.png]

Comment: Just put the code in the stylesheet you want. Firebug will not save your changes!

Comment: I have a plugin for my IDE that saves firebug css rules into my css file. So I can edit the rules of my css file in the firebug and it saves into my real css file directly. Its Why I would like to try to add rule in firebug to see if it also create that rule on my css file...

Answer (score 0):

yeah, just click at the end of `padding-top: 20px;`  , then hit return and you can define a NOT SAVED rule for app.css